# how to get response from json ajax call in codeigniter view?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, codeigniter

I am trying to get a response from the codeigniter controller in my view, but without success. Here is the code in my javascript file:

```
 // user enter his e-mail so check him against the database.
   $("#formSendPassword").submit(function(e){     

       e.preventDefault();

        var email = $(this).find("#checkemail").val();

        var obj = {email: email};
        var url = $(this).attr("action");
        var data =  {email: email};

        $.post(url, obj,data, function(jsonResp){
           console.log(success);
            if(jsonResp.success) {
                     alert(jsonResp['success']);
                    $('#successMailMessage').fadeIn();

          }  else {
                    alert("Fail");
                    $('#errorMailMessage').fadeIn();
                    }

        }, 'json');
    })
```

Code in my controller is as follow:

```
 public function checkEmail()
    {     
        // set the validation rules
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('checkemail', 'E-Mail', 'valid_email|required|trim|encode_php_tags');

        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<br /><p class=jsdiserr>', '</p><br />');
        // if validation is passed
        if ($this->form_validation->run() != FALSE) 
        {
            $ids=array();
            $ids[0]=$this->db->where('email', $this->input->post('checkemail'));

            $query = $this->backOfficeUsersModel->get();
            if($query)
            {

                $data = array(
                    'userid'       => $query[0]['userid'],
                    'username'       => $query[0]['username'],
                    'password'       => $query[0]['password'],
                    'firstname'       => $query[0]['firstname'],
                    'lastname'       => $query[0]['lastname'],
                    'email'       => $query[0]['email']
                ); 

                $jsonResp['success'] = "Ok";
                $jsonResp = array();
        } else {   
               // echo json_encode(array("success" => false, "error" => "Wrong email"));
                $jsonResp['success'] = "Fail";
        }
        //  form validation has failed 
        } else {     
            $errorMessage = "Please enter valid e-mail";
        }
    }   // end of function checkEmail
```

As you can see, i am trying to console.log  the success in my js file, but without success.
Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Regards,Zoran

Comment: Why do you try to pass both `obj` and `data` to `$.post`?

Comment: Where have you used `echo/print` to make output to the browser ?

Comment: i try to console log the output in the javascript but i get nothing back.

Comment: Musa i add them both, since none of them return any result back

Answer (score 0):

You should use a $data array element to store your json response before passing it to a view. This view is the json response your javascript callback is looking for. My guess would be that your console log call never fires.

Try the following:

In your Controller code something like:

```
 $data['json'] = json_encode(array("success" => false, "error" => "Wrong email"));
 $this->load->view('json_response', $data);
```

Define a view as follows:

```
<?php
    $this->output->set_header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    echo $json;
?>
```

You should also define a datatype in the jQuery call (dataType: "json").

EDIT: So your jQuery post call should look as follows:

```
$.post(url, data, function(data) {
    console.log(data.sucess);
}, "json");
```

You don't need to pass obj as well. Furthermore you need to log data.success, not just success. Let me know

Comment: What i am currently trying to do is to console.log the output from my controller code. I get noting in the code for the moment. After adding the  $data['json'] = json_encode(array("success" => false, "error" => "Wrong email")); i am trying to console.log the json in my javascript like this: console.log(jsonResp); but i get noting.

Comment: I see that you want to log from your controller - best practice would still be to do this via loading the view I wrote up. I have also added the specific jQuery function in my answer for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller is setting the final data but you are not printing it out. I didn't find your array being converted to json using json_encode and then printing it out.

Try that out. Plus you are populating the arrray and then why are you again doing an = array() ?

```
$jsonResp['success'] = "Ok";
$jsonResp = array();
```

See if this link helps you: http://amitavroy.com/justread/content/articles/getting-ajax-data-using-views-codeigniter

Comment: i add echo json_encode($jsonResp); bellow of the two lines above, and i get nothing. console.log is still empty. nothing happen.